# How to set Command from Content View Template

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a content page with CarouselViewControl. I am using template to display my picture and information. Now I am setting up a Command in my Template ContentView on the picture. However the event doesn't trigger. Do you see what I am doing wrong?

---

**ContentPage:**

```
<local:ExtendedCarouselViewControl
                            x:Name="lastThreeArticlesCarouselView"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Margin="0"
                            CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor="{DynamicResource BaseTextColor}"
                            HeightRequest="330"
                            IndicatorsTintColor="{DynamicResource TranslucidBlack}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding LastThreeArticles, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            ShowIndicators="True"
                            VerticalOptions="Start">
                            <cv:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <local:AvatArticlesBrowserHeaderItemTemplate />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </cv:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
</local:ExtendedCarouselViewControl>
```

...

```
public ArticleBrowser()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    var context = new MyArticlesBrowserViewModel(Navigation);
    Task.Run(async () => await context.LoadDataForBestSellers()).Wait();
    lastThreeArticlesCarouselView.ItemsSource = null;
    lastThreeArticlesCarouselView.ItemsSource = context.LastThreeArticles;    
}
```

---

**Template:**

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage
                Aspect="AspectFill"
                Source="{Binding BackgroundImage, Mode=TwoWay}"
                VerticalOptions="Fill">
                <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding PlayButtonCommand}" />
                </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

...

```
public Articles()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new MyArticlesBrowserViewModel();
}
```

---

**My Command:**

```
public MyArticlesBrowserViewModel(INavigation navigation) : base()
{
    PlayButtonCommand = new Command(async () => navigation.PushAsync(new Loader(Pages.Listening)));
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
 <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                Aspect="AspectFill"
                Source="{Binding BackgroundImage, Mode=TwoWay}"
                VerticalOptions="Fill">
                <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.PlayButtonCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=lastThreeArticlesCarouselView}}" />
                </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
            </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

I have tried this but still the event doesnt get called

Answer (score 0):

The `BindingContext` of your Template in this case is the `DataSource` of the `CarouselView` and not the `ViewModel`, you can reference it by indicating another `BindingContext` of an parent control like this:

```
{Binding BindingContext.PlayButtonCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=lastThreeArticlesCarouselView}}
```

Comment: you should use this where you are using the PlayButtonCommand (in your example:  <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.PlayButtonCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=lastThreeArticlesCarouselView}}" />
                </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>)

Comment: @VanessaKensington also, if this work, don't forget to mark it as the correct answer so others can see

Comment: the event still doesnt get triggered

Comment: Have you tried the `Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync` method?

Comment: in my case i am binding the command in Template and not the actual content page so the event doesnt get set is nit about the naviagtion

Comment: I shared a sample link, you could test the demo on your side.

Comment: @VanessaKensington Sorry for the delay, here are some less obvious problems that it might have something to do with the problem: 1 - Does your CarouselView has an layout overlaying it that might cause your gestures not to capture? 2 - if you put a button outside of your CarouselView does it trigger the command? 3 - Maybe the problem description is inducing us in error, what is the structure of the problem?

Comment: @VanessaKensington once you have tested the first 2 options and the results are not conclusive, you can try to describe in more detail the structure of your project

Comment: I'm going to open a chat here once you have tested the first 2 suggestions i gave you so you have more space to describe your problem

Comment: what is the structure of the project*